# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

Tags: java

```
public class constructor {

    class Person {
        private String name;
        private String birthday;
        private String sex;

        public Person( String name, String birthday, String sex) {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthday = birthday;
            this.sex = sex;
        }        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person obj=new Person("safwan","01--05-1999","male");

    }

}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    No enclosing instance of type constructor is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type constructor (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of constructor).

> at constructor.main(constructor.java:18)

Comment: Your `Person` class is an inner class so it has to have a reference to instance of `constructor` class (underneath). Move `Person` class to another java file or move `Person` class declaration outside of `constructor` class body, or add `static` to `class Person`.

Comment: I think naming a class `constructor` is one of the worst names I have ever seen.  Please follow proper Java naming conventions (class should be uppercase like your `Person`), and do not name something so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Person` class static:

```
public class constructor {

    static class Person {

        private String name;
        private String birthday;
        private String sex;

        public Person( String name, String birthday, String sex) {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthday = birthday;
            this.sex = sex;
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person obj=new Person("safwan","01--05-1999","male");
    }
}
```

so it will compile.